# MySQL, how to use returned data?

Tags: php, mysql

Well, I know there is a funciton mysql_fetch_array() and we can use it like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo $row['name'] . "<br />"; 
}
```

But is there any other way? For example, if there is only one element that can be returned, and not an array.

Thanks)

Comment: If you're new to mySQL with PHP do yourself a favor and ditch the mysql extension and read up either mysqli (mySQL improved) or PDO (PHP Data Objects). You'll thank me later. I don't belive that the mysql extension can do what you want, not sure if mysqli can, PDO can for sure.

Comment: Erik is absolutely correct. I'd also recommend the codesense mysqli wrapper - http://www.robpoyntz.com/blog/?p=189 - if you prefer mysqli over PDO.  I've used it on several occasions and it's a neat little class that hides much of the grunt work.

Comment: +1 for PDO.  There's a bit more to learn at the start but in the long term it will save a significant amount of time.

Comment: Remember your `htmlspecialchars()`, to avoid XSS problems.

Comment: Thank you all for advices) I found that net.tutsplus.com has an article about PDO, so I'm going to read it soon. Nevertheless, what is better to learn, MySQLi or PDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only going to be one row then you can just say:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Or you can use [mysql_fetch_row](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) if you want.

But I'd second Erik's comment to go with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Here's [a good tutorial making heavy use of PDO](http://ennuidesign.com/blog/Creating+an+App+from+Scratch+Part+5/).

Answer (score 4):

see [mysql_result()](http://docs.php.net/mysql_result):

> Retrieves the contents of one cell from a MySQL result set.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [mysql_result](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php)

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$scalar = mysql_result($result, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

> For example, if there is only one
>   element that can be returned, and not
>   an array.

Nope.
Only array or a useless object you can get.